# The Dart Analyzer could not be started in vscode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter, dart-analyzer

I just updated Dart version and then my vscode warning me everytime, "The Dart Analyzer could not be started".

[image]

How can i solve this issue ?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solved by uninstalling the Dart sdk manually from the computer, and re-install it.

If anyone face the same problem, please uninstall your dart sdk And install it again. Make sure you re-start your vscode IDE.

Hope this will helpful if you face the same problem.

--- Happy Coding ---

Comment: It would be better to click the "Show Log" button and if it's not clear from that log what's up, open an issue on GitHub for investigation :-)

Comment: So I found the answer to my question here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36257

After deleting the cache directory in the bin folder and re-running Flutter Doctor my problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

### solved..!

give permission to access the flutter folder.

### for MAC

- go to the security & privacy section
- then select the files and folders
- under your IDE,
- give permission to access the Flutter folder

[In my case I put the flutter folder inside the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYQa2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a permission issue. I just go through the log and seems unable to create .dart directory in the home folder.

Here is the solution:
 - This solution for mac only
 - cd ~
 - cd ..
 - whoami
 - sudo chown {username} {userfolder}

Answer (score 0):

In my case a simple restart of VSCode was needed - it seems as if there was a Dart update pending that VSCode did not notify me about.